# Laravel 5 recursive function many-to-many self referencing model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, recursion, laravel-5

I have a model called Product that has the following self referencing many-to-many relation:

```
// parent products based on the product_product pivot table
public function parent_products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_product', 'child_id', 'parent_id')->withPivot('amount');
}

// child products based on the product_product pivot table
public function child_products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_product', 'parent_id', 'child_id')->withPivot('amount');
}

// movements
public function movements()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Movement', 'product_id');
}
```

so any product can have "ideally" infinite ancestors and children.

Also any product is so a composition of other products as they are like "components".

So I need to return the amount of "producible" product based on availability of each children and their amounts needed to build the product.

No problems if this is a thing of one level depth, but the system should let you have many depth levels, so any child could be made from children as well.

I have no control on depth of each product->product->product chaining.

Apart from the performances issues, I need a recursive way to return the "producible" amount of each product in the chaining.

I managed how to get recursively the children till the end of the chain like this

```
public function child_products_recursive()
{
  return $this->child_products()->with(['child_products_recursive','movements'=>function($query){
    $query->whereDate('ready_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))->sum('amount');
  }]);
}
```

and it works.

But can't figure out how to return values out of this or how to navigate each model.

Involved tables are "simplified" like that:

```
products
---------
id | name
---------
1  | something
2  | something
3  | something
4  | something
5  | something
6  | something
7  | something


product_product
-----------------------------
parent_id | child_id | amount (amount of children in the parent product)
-----------------------------
1         | 2        | 2
1         | 3        | 4
2         | 4        | 1.5
2         | 5        | 3
4         | 6        | 0.7
4         | 7        | 0.3


movements table
-------------------------------------
id | product_id | date       | amount
-------------------------------------
1  | 4          | 2016-01-06 | 300
2  | 5          | 2016-01-06 | 200
3  | 6          | 2016-01-06 | 125
4  | 7          | 2016-01-06 | 1000
```

so product ID 1 don't have movements but can be built in many pieces based on the child products that don't have movements but can be build by child products as well.

Here's the visual representation (i didn't followed the data of the table before, but just to give the idea):

```
            Wine box        Wine box
            6 bottles       12 bottles ---1x-- Box for
            of Wine3        of Wine4           12 Bottles
               /  \             |   \          
              /    \            |    \
            x6      x1          |     x12
            /        \          |      \
         Bottle      Box for    |     Bottle
         of Wine3    6 Bottles  |     Label
         /  |  \                |        
        /   |   \              / \    
       /    |    \            /   \
      /     |     \          /     \
    x1    x0.75    x1      x12      x9
    /       |       \      /         \
Empty       |        Bottle         Wine4
Bottle XY   |        Cork ABC
            |        
            |        
            |
            |
          Wine3
         /    \
        /      \
     x0.7      x0.3
      /          \
   Wine1        Wine2
```

Thanks in advance.
Ciao

Comment: yes i think i would go with that approach but was wondering if any have gotten a similar problem and solved in a cleaner and simpler solution than my attempts

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i get the idea, but to test if the product **isProducible** i suggest something like:

```
public function getIsProducibleAttribute()
{
    if($this->movements > 0)
        return true;
    else{
        foreach($this->child_products_recursive as $child)
        {
            if(!$child->is_producible)
                return false;

            if($child->movements < $child->pivot->amount)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

If the product have the **movement** so its already there, else check the children, if **isProducible** check the **amount**, if fails for any child return **false**;

Let me try again:

```
public function getProducibleQuantityAttribute()
{
    $quantity = 0;
    foreach($this->child_products_recursive as $child)
    {
        //The production expected of that child with its stock and producible take in account.
        $child_producible = ($child->movements + 
                             $child->producible_quantity)
                            / $child->pivot->amount;

        //The first value
        if($quantity == 0)
            $quantity = $child_producible;
        //Takes the lowest
        else if($child_producible < $quantity) 
            $quantity = $child_producible;
    }

    return $quantity ;
    }
}
```

Thus, I check the stock and producible amount of children and divided by the amount required by the parent to make a unit. The lowest value is obtained, for example:

I have 24 bottles, but only a box of 12, so the answer is 1.

PS.: Dont forget to round, or not ;)

Comment: No, I need to know how many pieces of this item are producible.

Comment: Ok, and the movement is the stock? The products can have intersection between the child products? Like A is made of B and C, B is made of D, and  C is made of D and E, so if i use D to make B i have to discount to the producible C.

Comment: Exactly. The sum of movements related to product till current date represents the actual stock, but you can avoid consider this part and suppose it's already a number value (I'm thinking about appending that query as a value to product using appends, so each child will have as well).

Comment: And no, products can't have intersection fortunately. I edited the question to represent this graphically so it's more clear. Let's think at bottles of wine. 0.3 liter of Wine1 + 0.7 liter of Wine2 = 1 liter of Wine3. Then 1 liter of Wine3 + 1 Bottle type23 + 1 Cork type7 + 1 Label type35 = Bottle of Wine3. Then 6 Bottles of Wine3 + 1 Box for 6 = Wine3 Box of 6. But also 12 Bottles of Wine3 + 1 Box for 12 = Wine3 Box of 12 and Wine21 + 1 Bottle type23 + 1 Cork type7 + 1 Label type65 = Bottle of Wine21. Check my edit on answer for visual representation.